# Setting up Varnish with Nginx on multiple sites

Tags: nginx, web, server, ubuntu-16.04, varnish

I was trying to set up Varnish 4.1 with Nginx 1.12.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 for the past couple of days. I read the documentation and many different sources but I can't seem to get a good handle on things. The website is in a redirect loop, and when I use the command: varnishd -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -d I receive this error: Cannot open socket: :80: Address already in use.

To clarify, I'm trying to set up nginx to receive HTTPS (also redirec HTTP to HTTPS) send this to Varnish and then return to nginx if a cache misses. Thank you so much in advance to anyone who can point me in the right direction.

I have set up my nginx to look like this (/etc/nginx/sites-available/fujiorganics.com):

```
server {
listen 80;
listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/fujiorganics.com/fullchain.pem; 
# managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key 
/etc/letsencrypt/live/fujiorganics.com/privkey.pem; # managed by 
Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by 
Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by 
Certbot
    if ($scheme != "https") {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }

 # managed by Certbot

root /var/www/fujiorganics.com/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name fujiorganics.com www.fujiorganics.com;
# Proxy Pass to Varnish
    # Add headers to recognize SSL
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.2;
        # Pass a bunch of headers to the downstream server, so 
they'll know what's going on.
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    # Most web apps can be configured to read this header and 
understand that the current session is actually HTTPS.
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

    # We expect the downsteam servers to redirect to the right 
hostname, so don't do any rewrites here.
    proxy_redirect     off;
    }
}
```

And my varnish configuration files look like this (/etc/varnish/default.vcl):

```
    vcl 4.0;

# List of upstream proxies we trust to set X-Forwarded-For correctly.
backend default {
  .host = "127.0.0.1";
  .port = "8080";
}


backend fujiorganics {
  .host = "127.0.0.2";
  .port = "8080";
}


sub vcl_recv {

 # Remove any Google Analytics based cookies
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "__utm.=[^;]+(; )?", "");
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "_ga=[^;]+(; )?", "");
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "_gat=[^;]+(; )?", "");
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "utmctr=[^;]+(; )?", "");
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "utmcmd.=[^;]+(; )?", "");
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "utmccn.=[^;]+(; )?", "");

  # Remove Optimizely Cookies
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "optim.=[^;]+(; )?", "");
  # Remove Gauges Cookies
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "_gau.=[^;]+(; )?", "");


# Remove a ";" prefix in the cookie if present
  set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "^;\s*", "");

  # Are there cookies left with only spaces or that are empty?
  if (req.http.cookie ~ "^\s*$") {
    unset req.http.cookie;
  }

   if (req.restarts == 0) {
    if (req.http.x-forwarded-for) {
      set req.http.X-Forwarded-For =
        req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
      } else {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
      }
  }

  if (req.method != "GET" &&
      req.method != "HEAD" &&
      req.method != "PUT" &&
      req.method != "POST" &&
      req.method != "TRACE" &&
      req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
      req.method != "DELETE") {
        /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
        return (pipe);
   }
   if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        /* We only deal with GET and HEAD by default */
      return (pass);
  }

  if ( (req.http.host ~ "^(?i)fujiorganics.com") && req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto !~ "(?i)https") {

        set req.backend_hint = fujiorganics;
        set req.http.x-redir = "https://" + req.http.host + req.url;
        return (synth(750, ""));
  }
 return (hash);
}

# handles redirecting from http to https
sub vcl_synth {
  if (resp.status == 750) {
    set resp.status = 301;
    set resp.http.Location = req.http.x-redir;
    return(deliver);
  }
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
  set beresp.ttl = 10s;
  set beresp.grace = 1h;
}

sub vcl_deliver {
  if (obj.hits > 0) { # Add debug header to see if it's a HIT/MISS and the number of hits, disable when not needed
    set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
  } else {
    set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
  }
}
```

And this (/etc/systemd/system/varnish.service.d/customexec.conf):

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -a :8080 -T localhost:6082 -f 
/etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s default,1G
```

Finally this server block is contained in the same file as the first lsited above

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080;

    root /var/www/fujiorganics.com/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name 127.0.0.2;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                # With php7.0-cgi alone:
                #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #        With php7.0-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

}
```

I can confirm that the website works perfectly well without the varnish redirection.

Answer (score 1):

Varnish is trying to talk to Nginx on port 8080, but Nginx listens on port 80 which is also the port Varnish wants to listens to.
COnfigure Varnish to listens on port 80, Nginx to listen on 8080 and it should work.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. Is it possible to change varnish to only listen to port 8080 instead?

Comment: Yes, but then Nginx will have to listen on another port.

Comment: @AriannaAondio Does your configuration work with https?